# Adjacent package does not exist

Tags: java, import, package

I have a `public class Mountain` in `Four\ Seasons\ Lab/things/Mountain.java` and try to import the class `public class Triangle`, which is in `Four\ Seasons\ Lab/shapes/Triangle.java`, using `import shapes.Triangle` (note: `import shapes.*` also doesn't work). For some reason, this keeps throwing `package shapes does not exist`, as well as `cannot find symbol` on any time I try to use the `Triangle` class. How do I fix this?

**Mountain.java**

```
package things;

import shapes.Triangle;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Mountain {
    private Triangle body;

    public Mountain(int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
        this.body = new Triangle(
            x, y + dy,
            x + dx/2, y,
            x + dx, y + dy
        );
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        body.draw(g);
    }
}
```

**Triangle.java**

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Triangle {
    private Color color;
    private int[] pointA;
    private int[] pointB;
    private int[] pointC;
    
    public Triangle(Color color, int aX, int aY, int bX, int bY, int cX, int cY) {
        this.color = color;
        this.pointA = new int[] {aX, aY};
        this.pointB = new int[] {bX, bY};
        this.pointC = new int[] {cX, cY};
    }
    // more code
}
```

[File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOLk.png)

[Screenshot of Mountain.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyiV7.png)

Note:

1. `Runner` will run `Scenery`, which will run `Mountain`
2. The program must run in terminal through:

```
(in "Four Seasons Lab" directory)
$ javac *.java
$ java Runner
```

(it is shared via a .zip file containing only the .java files)

Comment: Perform a "clean and build" with your IDE, rather than just trying to run the code, and it should resolve your issue

Comment: @sorifiend and how do I do that? I am running this directly from terminal on mac

Comment: The screenshot you posted is from an IDE, not the terminal. The IDE should have an option to clean and compile the code before you attempt to run it from the terminal. Even if you are running/compiling from the terminal, please edit your question to include the exact and full compilation/runtime error, because I can't see any issues with the code itself other than the `Triangle` constructor requires a `Color` and six `int` args, but your mountain class only passes three `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with my IDE or my code or anything. I am using Atom as an IDE and `linter-javac` package as a linter. This is just a problem with the linter.